# Persisting only some fields from the Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-persist

Hi in our app we have a reducer pattern:

```
{
   data: //here we have our actual data
   fetching: // is it still fetching 
   intact: // has it been 'touched'
   error: //errors if need be
}
```

furthermore due to business demand I need to persist a ReduxForm which is its own can of worms...

```
form: {
    Foobar: {
      values: {

      },
      initial: {

      },
      syncErrors: {

      },
      registeredFields: {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

it is as you may have figured out is pointless to persist anything but data, but Redux-Persist persists the entire reducer. The examples on filtering and transformation is a bit... lackluster in my feel and I have been strugling to implement. Looking for an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok so this works using redux-persist-transform-filter like @NickHTTPS sugested:

```
import createFilter from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';

const saveSubsetFilter = createFilter('form', ['Foo.bar']);

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'form',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['form'],
    transforms: [saveSubsetFilter]
};

persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, { form: formReducer });
```

works like a charm :)

Comment: Is it possible to persist a key on a store that is blackListed ?

Comment: I checked the lib and I can see this code 
`    function passWhitelistBlacklist(key) {
      if (whitelist && whitelist.indexOf(key) === -1) return false
      if (blacklist.indexOf(key) !== -1) return false
      return true
    }`
Which is checked on update of persist and getting of stored state so, I don't think you can do that as the check will omit it by definition. 
You can whitelist a store and the filter what gets stored from there.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to whitelist/blacklist keys in redux-persist:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'form',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['Foobar'] // only Foobar will be persisted
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

Unfortunately **whitelist/blacklist** only accepts 1 level deep so I think you need to use something like this: https://github.com/edy/redux-persist-transform-filter or rework your data structure in a way that you can bypass the 1 level deep limitation of the library.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks man, yeah we are aware of what is there, but transforms are applied at store level right? Kind of makes a mess in the application in my opinion. I am still hoping someone figured it out...

Comment: It should work per single reducer:
```// you want to remove some keys before you save
const saveSubsetBlacklistFilter = createBlacklistFilter(
  'myReducerTwo',
  ['keyYouDontWantToSave1', 'keyYouDontWantToSave2']
);```
I haven't tried this library myself though. In the past I just structured my data to be only 1 level deep.

Comment: yeah it works, furthermore allows you to drill it down 'keyYouDontWantToSave2.data' :)

Comment: Good to hear that :)